# Second menu overrides first why?

Tags: themes

i've created a custom theme, and this is my function:

```
function add_main_nav() {
    
    if( !is_nav_menu( 'scp-main-menu' )){
        register_nav_menu('scp-main-menu',__( 'Main Menu' ));
        $menu_id = wp_create_nav_menu( 'scp-main-menu' );
        wp_update_nav_menu_item( $menu_id, 0, array(
            'menu-item-title' => 'Sobre mí',
            'menu-item-url' => '#scp-abaout-me',
            'menu-item-status' => 'publish',
            'menu-item-type' => 'custom', 
        ) );
        wp_update_nav_menu_item( $menu_id, 0, array(
            'menu-item-title' => 'Experiencia',
            'menu-item-url' => '#scp-experience-block',
            'menu-item-status' => 'publish',
            'menu-item-type' => 'custom', 
        ) );
        wp_update_nav_menu_item( $menu_id, 0, array(
            'menu-item-title' => 'Projects',
            'menu-item-url' => '#scp-projects-block',
            'menu-item-status' => 'publish',
            'menu-item-type' => 'custom', 
        ) );
         
    }
    
    if( !is_nav_menu( 'scp-footer-menu' )){
        register_nav_menu('scp-footer-menu',__( 'Footer Menu' ));
        $footer_menu_id = wp_create_nav_menu( 'scp-footer-menu' );
        wp_update_nav_menu_item( $footer_menu_id, 0, array(
            'menu-item-title' => 'Sobre mí',
            'menu-item-url' => '#scp-abaout-me',
            'menu-item-status' => 'publish',
            'menu-item-type' => 'custom', 
        ) );
       
    }

}
// Hook to the init action hook, run our navigation menu function
add_action( 'init', 'add_main_nav' );



header.php:
 <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'header-menu' => 'header-menu' ) ); ?>


footer.php:
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
<footer>
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'footer-menu' => 'footer-menu' ) ); ?>
    <p>Copyright &copy; 2024 taniarroyo.com</p>
</footer>
```

thanks!!!

I want to show 2 different menus, one in the header and one in the footer, it generates them correctly, but the one I generated for the footer is always displayed also in the header.